# QWebengine not working on Qtcreator with Qt5.13.2 on window 10 32 bits

Tags: c++, qt, websocket, qwebview, qwebengine

I've been trying to compile a code on Qt creator with Qt 5.13.2 on windows 10 32 bit, but it displaying QWebengine not found, I search online to get solution, but I only saw solution on Visual Studio Qt, my pc has no VS installation.

Comment: Your findings are correct - webengine currently cannot be build with MinGW on windows so QtWebEngine can't be either.

Comment: – chehrlic, please what is the way forward? what can I do?

Comment: Use MSVC if you want to use QtWebEngine. Or port webengine to work with MinGW